# XPath - Get textcontent() and HTML

Tags: xpath, domdocument

Lets say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="some-class">
     <p> some paragraph</p>
     <h2>a heading</h2>
</div>
```

I want to grab everything in `<div class='some-class'>`, including the HTML.  The following only grabs the text:

```
$descriptions = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'some-class')]");
foreach($descriptions as $description)
       print $description->textContent;
```

Whats the best way of getting the contained HTML tags as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function - I've never found any built in function but this works well:

```
function getInnerHTML($node)
{
    $innerHTML = "";
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));        
        $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML(); 
    } 
    return $innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to retrieve the `outerXml` - have a look at [DOMDocument::saveXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php). Or have I misunderstood you - do you just need the xml serialization of the `<div>` element and its attribute axis?

**Edit** I mean do you want:

```
<div class="some-class">
     <p> some paragraph</p>
     <h2>a heading</h2>
</div>
```

or just

```
<div class="some-class" />
```

?

Comment: I just need to pull a particular portion of an HTML page, based on the tag, and get everything contained with it's open and closing tags, including text content, and html

Comment: neither actually.  In the above, I just want the `<p> some paragraph</p> <h2>a heading</h2>`.  Which is to say, everything contained with in the <div> i searched by

Comment: There are a couple of hacks to get the `innerXml` on the Php link - e.g. see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#63640)